# A Hybrid (WebView) Android App that sends device data on POST

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am looking for a way to make an Android app that uses device data and that would occasionally send device data, such as GPS location, device UUID (or any other unique identifier for that matter), and a Push notifications token (when it is received). All depends on the interaction with UI Elements inside the html.

So the mobile app would have an html button (I assume with a specific `id`?) that sends a request to the server with the GPS data, in POST.
Another button would send the Push-notifications token, and another button would send the device UUID.

How can something like that be achieved? Are there specific frameworks that we need to use?

Answer (score 0):

To retreive gps information and the uuid of the device you might want to use the [geolocation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-geolocation) and the [device plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-device).
To POST the information to a server you might want to use some library or framework. jQuery might be a reasonable choice, documentation on how to perform a post using jQuery can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). Of course other frameworks or libraries might do the job as well...